# Return to parent form once I submit on popup form

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Ok... here is a situation. I've 2 forms

1. parent.jsp
2. popup.jsp

When I click on "ADD User" link on parent.jsp, popup.jsp opens in a new window... I enter details of user and hit submit button. User details are stored in database. Everything goes fine till now. But after that it opens parent.jsp in one more tab (which I don't want). It should just return to same tab and refresh the page.

Comment: share the code you tried.

Comment: <p><a href="UserController?action=insert" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');return false;">Add User</a></p>

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a href="UserController?action=insert" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');return false;">Add User</a></p>
```

Above code snippet is from parent.jsp. This works just fine. I'm trying following in my popup.jsp, but its not working. Not sure if this is a correct way to do it.

```
    window.onunload() = function () {
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
```